# Open a folder window using explorer.exe or finder using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, explorer, finder

I was wondering if there was a way to open a folder location via node js. I found [this library](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open) but it only opens files and URLs.

Edit: Fuser's answer put me on the right track and I found this:

http://documentup.com/arturadib/shelljs

Either his method or this will both work.

Comment: Which exact shelljs command did you end up using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just shell out to `explorer` with the desired folder.

Comment: Would this work for Mac and Linux alongside Windows?

Comment: No. You'll have to detect environment. On mac use `open` and in linux it's a bit tougher, but you'd use `gnome-open` on ubuntu.

Comment: the second answer which @kim T proided is the [complete version] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68010888/12666332)

Answer (score 3):

Simply just use `child_process.exec` or `child_process.execSync` along with the right **shell command**. Here is a working example:

```
function dirOpen(dirPath) {
  let command = '';
  switch (process.platform) {
    case 'darwin':
      command = 'open';
      break;
    case 'win32':
      command = 'explorer';
      break;
    default:
      command = 'xdg-open';
      break;
  }
  console.log('child_process.execSync', `${command} "${dirPath}"`);
  return child_process.execSync(`${command} "${dirPath}"`);
}
```

Comment: This should be `child_process.exec` or `child_process.execSync` instead of `fs`