# Open a directory in File Explorer

Tags: node.js, windows

On ms Windows from **node.js** code, how can I open a specific directory (ex: `c:\documents`) in Windows file explorer?

I guess in **c#**, it would be:

```
process.Start(@"c:\test")
```

Comment: `start c:\test`, for the actual command line call... `c:\test` by itself won't do anything in a shell...

Comment: Here is a *fully working* example for **windows/macos/linux**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68010888/12666332

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try the following, which opens a File Explorer window *on the computer running this code*:

```
require('child_process').exec('start "" "c:\\test"');
```

If your path doesn't contain whitespace, you can also get away with `'start c:\\test'`, but the above - which requires `""` as the 2nd argument<sup>[1]</sup> is the most robust approach.

Note:

- The File Explorer window will launch *asynchronously*, and will *receive focus* when it does.
- [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59755890/45375) asks for a solution that prevents the window from "stealing" focus.

---

<sup>[1] `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command by default interprets a `"..."`-enclosed 1st argument as the *window title* for the new console window to create (which doesn't apply here). By supplying a (dummy) window title - `""` - explicitly, the 2nd argument is reliably interpreted as the target executable / document path.</sup>

Comment: advice noted. thanks @mklement0
I am trying to develop a web application that browses a shared network folder.

Is it possible to open the folder in my local machine by  a web app that is hosted on another machine. it will only issue the open command:

**require('child_process').exec('start "" "E:\\test"');**

The other machine could be in LAN or the internet. I will access the app from my local macnine. 
basically, I will implement a navigation menu to navigate quickly to the required folder in our server. Later, I will add some code to check which folders are empty.

Comment: @Abdullah: This is outside my area of expertise, but I suspect that browser security restrictions (sandboxing) will be an issue. I suggest you ask a separate, follow-up question (that links to this one) that provides more details and shows how far you got. Also note that it, if it's permitted at all, it would have to be _local_ JavaScript, run by the _browser_ that opens the folder - no Node.js involved (unless you somehow manage to call a `node` command _locally_).

Comment: this will open a directory on the PC running the node service only, not on clients connecting to it

Answer (score 7):

Would be good to use this package so it would open on diffrent platform
https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-file-explorer

Or just use this part of it

```js
function openExplorerin(path, callback) {
    var cmd = ``;
    switch (require(`os`).platform().toLowerCase().replace(/[0-9]/g, ``).replace(`darwin`, `macos`)) {
        case `win`:
            path = path || '=';
            cmd = `explorer`;
            break;
        case `linux`:
            path = path || '/';
            cmd = `xdg-open`;
            break;
        case `macos`:
            path = path || '/';
            cmd = `open`;
            break;
    }
    let p = require(`child_process`).spawn(cmd, [path]);
    p.on('error', (err) => {
        p.kill();
        return callback(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found another way on the WSL and potentially windows itself.

Note that you have to make sure you're formatting the path for Windows not Linux (WSL).
I wanted to save something on Windows, so in order to do that you use `/mnt` directory on WSL.

```js
// format the path, so Windows isn't mad at us
// first we specify that we want the path to be compatible with windows style
// then we replace the /mnt/c/ with the format that windows explorer accepts
// the path would look like `c:\\Users\some\folder` after this line
const winPath = path.win32.resolve(dir).replace('\\mnt\\c\\', 'c:\\\\');

// then we use the same logic as the previous answer but change it up a bit
// do remember about the "" if you have spaces in your name
require('child_process').exec(`explorer.exe "${winPath}"`);
```

This should open the file explorer for you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```
const open = require('open')
open(folderPath)
```

For me it works without installing "open" package, but IDE asks me to install

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler, and more cross-platform solution, would be to use this.

```js
let explorer;
switch (platform()) {
    case "win32": explorer = "explorer"; break;
    case "linux": explorer = "xdg-open"; break;
    case "darwin": explorer = "open"; break;
}
spawn(explorer, [path], { detached: true }).unref();
```

`platform()` is from the `os` module, and `spawn` is from the `child_process` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `explorer-opener` package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/explorer-opener

```
import { openExplorer } from 'explorer-opener';

openExplorer('C:\\Windows\\System32')
  .then(() => {
    // handle successful open
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle error
  });
```